# Creating user aliases in gmail using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-forms, google-directory-api

I am reading in alias email information from a google form entry and I wish to use it to create an alias email.

[This link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-user-aliases) talks about using the directory API to accomplish this but from its description about setting up authorization etc. it seems to be for a web application.

How do I create an email alias for an account using a Google apps script associated with my Google Form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Admin SDK's Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) in Apps Script, but you need to use the [Advanced Admin SDK Directory service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) (That must be [enabled before use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). In the Script Editor select **Resources > Advanced Google services**... and then enable it in the **Google Developers Console**.)

Once enabled you can add an alias like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var userKey = 'jane.doe@mydomain.com';
  var resource = {
    alias: 'jenny@mydomain.com'
  }

  AdminDirectory.Users.Aliases.insert(resource, userKey)
}
```

Then you can verify the alias in your **Admin Console** in **Users > Select User > Account > Aliases**:

[image]