# Is there any way to mail merge with my own domain name instead Gmail

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here what I want to do is :

1. Send an email by mail merge by writing a script in App Script. (Success)
2. I have configured 2 domain email addresses in my Gmail along with my basic Gmail address.
   I want to send an email via xyz@domainname.com instead of xyz@gmail.com, the Google Sheets owner.
   here what I have done to send an email via Gmail

```
  var first = 0;
  var last = 1;
  var email = 2;
  
  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NAJ");

  var data = ws.getRange("A2:C" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

  data.forEach(function(row){
    
    emailTemp.fn = row[first];
    emailTemp.ln = row[last];
    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(row[email], "Important Test", "Your email does not support HTML.",
    {name: "Email App", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
    );

  });

}
```

The only thing I need is to change the sending email address.
Any help would be highly appreciated. pardon my bad English

[image: This is my database]

Comment: You need to create aliases in you gmail account

Comment: @Cooper yes I thought the same and then I saw that you need to be a google workspace admin to do that. However, I posted it as one of the approaches. The other one could be to use an installable trigger.

Comment: @Marios Thanks I didn’t know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to send emails from a specific email account regardless of the email account that is currently executing the script.

**Approach 1:**

- One way to approach that is to use an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) trigger. As per the documentation:

> Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who
> created them. For example, if you create an installable open trigger,
> it runs when your colleague opens the document (if your colleague has
> edit access), but it runs as your account. This means that if you
> create a trigger to send an email when a document is opened, the email
> is always be sent from your account, not necessarily the account that
> opened the document.

The idea here is to create an installable `onEdit` trigger from `xyz@domainname.com` so whenever the other emails **edit** a particular cell, the emails will be send.

The limitation of this approach is that we need to make sure that we trigger the code when we really want to and not every time a cell is edited. We can create a checkbox, and upon clicking on the checkbox (it does not matter which account did that) then the script will be executed and the emails will sent by the email account who created the installable trigger.

**Approach 2:**

Create email aliases. [Here](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6304345?hl=en) is the official documentation on how to do that and also this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373788/creating-user-aliases-in-gmail-using-google-apps-script) might be useful to create them programmatically. The restriction here is that to add an email alias, you must be a Google Workspace administrator.

### Solutions:

**Solution 1:**

1. Create a checkbox in cell **D1** of the sheet **NAJ**. The cell is up to you but you need to adjust the script accordingly.
2. Change the name of the function to add the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). This will allow us to get edit info such as which cell is edited.

The new function will be:

```
function myInstallableOnEditFunction(e) {
  
  const arng = e.range;
  
  if(arng.getSheet().getName()=="NAJ" && arng.getA1Notation()=='D1' && arng.getValue()==true){
  
    var first = 0;
    var last = 1;
    var email = 2;
    
    var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
    
    var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NAJ");
    
    var data = ws.getRange("A2:C" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
    
    data.forEach(function(row){
      
      emailTemp.fn = row[first];
      emailTemp.ln = row[last];
      var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
      GmailApp.sendEmail(row[email], "Important Test", "Your email does not support HTML.",
                         {name: "Email App", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
                        );
      
    });
  }
}
```

Finally, create an installable `onEdit` trigger function from the `xyz@domainname.com` account. You can do that either [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47676087/11225291) from the current project's trigger menu or [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666338/11225291).

After that, upon clicking on cell **D1** by any account, the emails will be sent by `xyz@domainname.com`.

**Solution 2:**

After you have created email aliases (see **Approach 2**), you can use the [getAliases()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getAliases()) method, here is a sample script. I haven't tested on my own, but you can explore also this possibility.

```
// Log the aliases for this Gmail account and send an email as the first one.
var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
Logger.log(aliases);
if (aliases.length > 0) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': aliases[0]});
} else {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'No aliases found', 'You have no aliases.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is that this sheet is not shared with anyone. I m the only owner of this sheet, and nobody needs to access this. My code does 90% of the work. I want to send an email from me@mydoamin.com, not me@gmail.com. me@mydomain.com is already added as an alias in my Gmail. and for the trigger, i will create a button that's not the issue.

Comment: Solution 2 worked. I just needed getAliases() to get it work.